# Angular Cli - Import component service from anoter component

Tags: angular

How can I import a component service from another component?

this is my project structure

[image]

I want to import "organization.service" on the user-form.component.

I tried

```
import { OrganizationService } from '.../organizations/shared/organization.service';
```

with no success, I get an error saying 'Cannot find module'

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import { OrganizationService } from '../../organizations/shared/organization.service';
```

Two dots instead of three and you need to go up one more level.